# Google Colab unzipped file won't appear

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have downloaded some datasets via Kaggle API into Colab. However, after unzipping them they do not appear in my directory and I can read them with pandas

[image: Colab commands]

As you can see the file where successfully unzip and then I unzip them again as I couldn't find them. However, they do no appear in the directory as I mentioned. 
Furthermore the `pd.read_csv` can't read either the `csv` files that don't show or the `csv.zip` that show using `compression = zip` argument.
I get

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'/data/train.csv' does not exist
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/train.csv.zip'
```

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

try unzipping them individually like

```
!unzip train.csv.zip
```

then do

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv', nrows=6000000, dtype={'acoustic_data': np.int16, 'time_to_failure': np.float64})
```

I got this from this github repo, which you can follow the steps for or just import into colab then replace it with your data

https://github.com/llSourcell/Kaggle_Earthquake_challenge/blob/master/Earthquake_Challenge.ipynb

you can import .ipynb notebooks through searching for them in colab

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried unzipping the files individually and they were still not accessible.

Comment: do you a have a link to your colab notebook to look at?